# mono DataAdapter it error?

Tags: android, mono, monodevelop

I could not understand why a process fails while installing the DataTable I'm doing wrong

```
        Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataAdapter da=new 
                         SqliteDataAdapter("select * from custome",con);
        System.Data.DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        dt.BeginLoadData();
        da.Fill(dt);//Error
        dt.EndLoadData();
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is the native sqlite3 library isn't compiled with SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA on a mac. Solution is to download sources, compile with said setting and override the default lib with the newly compiled one. Haven't quite figured out the last part yet. Here's another related thread:

[Mono on OS X: System.Data.SQLite does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090152/mono-on-os-x-system-data-sqlite-does-not-work)