# Using a custom build of Sqlite inside a MonoMac app

Tags: macos, sqlite, mono, dylib, monomac

I've built a custom version of libsqlite3 to fix [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090152/mono-on-os-x-system-data-sqlite-does-not-work) in the standard sqlite library.

The question is, how can this library (and the associated managed System.Data.SQLite.dll) be packaged inside a MonoMac app bundle? Exact steps please, have spent days trying to solve this.

Note: this is a MonoMac .app bundle, not a mono .exe. This [thread](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/libsqlite3-0-dylib-SQLITE-ENABLE-COLUMN-METADATA-required-td1548412.html) explains what to do in case of a mono .exe.